# Attaching multiple files through MIMEs to a document in Lotus Domino

Tags: java, mime-types, attachment, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In our enterprise application we need to attach files to a document. We have the filename and the content of the file in a byte array. I found a solution to attach a file to a document with MIMEs:

```
    final MIMEEntity body = document.createMIMEEntity(fileName);
    final MIMEHeader bodyHeader = body.createHeader("Content-Disposition");

    final boolean isHeaderValSet = bodyHeader.setHeaderVal("attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    if (!isHeaderValSet) {
        throw new ComponentException("Could not set MIME header value.");
    }

    body.setContentFromBytes(fileContentOutput, mimeType, MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY);
    final boolean saveSuccessful = document.save();
    if (!saveSuccessful) {
        throw new Exception("Cannot attach file " + fileName + "to document: " + documentUniversalId);
    }
```

This method seems to work for a file, but when I try to upload another one I get the following exception:

> NotesException: Item body already exists

Is there a way to attach multiple files to a document, when you only have the name of the file and the contents in a byte array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep the first line where you create the "parent" MIMEEntity called body.  Then in a loop, create child MIMEentities for all the files you wish to include:

```
final MIMEEntity child = body.CreateChildEntity;
child.setHeaderVal("attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
child.createHeader("Content-Disposition");
child.setContentFromBytes(fileContentOutput, mimeType, MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY);
```

[CreateChildEntity](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CREATECHILDENTITY_METHOD_MIMEENTITY_JAVA.html)

Comment: It seems a good solution but after I applied it, I got the same exception on the document.createMIMEEntity() method. Its odd since I check the existence of the entity:

`final Session notesSession = session.getSession();
notesSession.setConvertMIME(false);

MIMEEntity body = document.getMIMEEntity();
if (body == null) {
 body = document.createMIMEEntity();
}`

Comment: Found the solution on the web: http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20120131-0656

Thank you for the answer!